# Replace / mask word in URL using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have a site which has a url structure like so:

url/example1/sometext

So I dont have to go through and change a crazy amount of code, can I use htaccess to do the following?

url/newword/sometext redirects to: url/example1/sometext with url/newword/sometext still shown the address bar.

I have tried some rewrites like:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)example1(.*)$ url/$1newword$2 [R=301,L]`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the "url" part is still the same, then you can just get rid of the `R=301` flag:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)example1(.*)$ /$1newword$2 [L]
```

Comment: Hi Jon, 

Thanks for that. I believe in theory this should work. I am still getting 404's when visiting url/newword. Any ideads? Here is my htaccess: 

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)example1(.*)$ /$1newword$2 [L]
</IfModule>

`

Comment: So I know itsworking - kind of. Its breaking all my css files that have 'example1' in the URL. It isn't affect the url (http://webpage.com/example1).